# Hibernate JPA joinTable share ID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have trouble with saving entities to data base.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseJpa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="genres")
public class GenreJpa extends BaseJpa{

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="movies")
public class MovieJpa extends BaseJpa{

    @Type(type="text")
    private String name;

    private String releaseDate;

    @Type(type="text")
    private String summary;

    @JoinTable(name = "movie_genres", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<GenreJpa> genres;

    private long votes;

    private double rank;

    public long getVotes() {
        return votes;
    }

    public void setVotes(long votes) {
        this.votes = votes;
    }

    public double getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(double rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public List<GenreJpa> getGenres() {
        return genres;
    }

    public void setGenres(List<GenreJpa> genres) {
        this.genres = genres;
    }
```

Having these entities, I do 2 iterations:

1. I persist a list of genres (34 objects). Check my data base table, and I can fetch all 34 genres.
2. I persist a movie list (over 1 mil. objects). Now every movie object has a list of genres, and those genres are being inserted into genres table with different IDs. Is it no possible to make it share already inserted genres? To not make any more inserts into genres?

Methods used to insert data:

```
public void batchInsertMovies(List<MovieJpa> movies){
    EntityManager entityManager = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    try{
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        int i = 0;
        for(MovieJpa movie : movies){
            entityManager.persist(movie);
            i++;
            if(i == 30){
                //flush a batch of inserts and release memory
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
            }
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}

public void batchInsertGenres(List<GenreJpa> genres){
    EntityManager entityManager = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    try{
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        int i = 0;
        for(GenreJpa genre : genres){
            entityManager.persist(genre);
            i++;
            if(i == 5){
                //flush a batch of inserts and release memory
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
            }
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you have OneToMany join table? Shouldn't it be ManyToMany?

Comment: You are correct, it should be ManyToMany. Upvoting your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
entityManager.persist(movie);
```

The movie contains genres. Each Genre instance in this collection should have id field populated, otherwise Hibernate will think it's a new object and will try to persist it if cascade option is appropriate.